# Remove Time from a Date column

Tags: oracle, postgresql, sqldatatypes

We are migrating our Database from Oracle to PostgreSQL.

Currently we are using trunc(date) to remove time from a date column.
I would like to know a common solution that works for both Oracle as well as postgreSQL db?

Comment: The `extract` function works on both, IIRC. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm#i1017161) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: We need a common solution because DB change would be done in one environment at a time. So basically the same query should run in different environments with different DB.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `date` in Postgres?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca how exactly can I extract the date using extract ? from the example I see that only an element of the date can be extracted.

Comment: Nitpicking: `trunc()` does not "remove" the time in Oracle. It only sets it to `00:00:00`

Comment: @sijojosan you extract one piece of the date at the time and then concatenate them

Answer (score 4):

you can cast it to date in postgresql

like this

```
SELECT timestamp '2009-12-22 11:01:46'::date
>>> 2009-12-22
```

Answer (score 1):

You may create an overloaded `TRUNC` function in Postgresql.

```
CREATE FUNCTION TRUNC ( dttm TIMESTAMP ) RETURNS TIMESTAMP 
AS
$$
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('DAY',$1);
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE;

select TRUNC(NOW()::timestamp);

12.03.2018 00:00:00
```